# Capistrano can't find a JavaScript runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, rvm, capistrano

I have a problem with Capistrano deploying to a server with RVM and gemsets

```
executing `deploy:assets:precompile'
* executing "cd /var/app/releases/20111229233555 && rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
*** [err ::] rake aborted!
*** [err ::] Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell '1.9.2@mygemset' -c 'cd /var/app/releases/20111229234715 && rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile'"
```

This is my Capfile

```
  $:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))
  require 'rvm/capistrano'
  set :rvm_bin_path, "$HOME/.rvm/bin"
  set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.2@mygemset'
  set :rvm_type, :user
  load 'deploy/assets'
```

When I log in as the very same user which is used by Capistrano the failing command is executed without any problems.

It seems that Capistrano is using some other environment.

Here is my `~/.rvmrc` file:

```
   rvm_gemset_create_on_use_flag=1 rvm_trust_rvmrcs_flag=1
```

Is there a way how to check which ruby and gemset is used at the execution time?

node.js is and V8 are installed on the system, and all needed gems are in Gemfile:

here is my `rvm info`:

```
   ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.2p290"
    date:         "2011-07-09"
    platform:     "x86_64-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2011-07-09 revision 32553"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/home/capistrano/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@mygemset"
    ruby:         "/home/capistrano/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/home/capistrano/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/home/capistrano/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/home/capistrano/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/home/capistrano/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@mygemset/bin/rake"
```

Comment: these problems are normally to do with the PATH variable not being set by capistrano. consider prefixing a `PATH="/path/to/v8:$PATH"` to the start of your rake command to debug.

Comment: execjs is probably looking for a `node` binary. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction!

Comment: Users developing on **Windows** should [read this Gist](https://gist.github.com/3326247) I wrote about Capistrano and 'Could not find a JavaScript runtime'. Hope this will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting up PATH in the `deploy.rb` solved this issue:

```
default_environment['PATH'] = "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:$PATH"
```

it's a Gentoo distribution and the `PATH` var seems to be empty when using `cap deploy`, so I copied the content of server `PATH` and now it works

Answer (score 1):

This issue went away for me when I installed nodejs (using apt-get) on my server.  As I stated in [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038350/bundle-install-issue-with-libv8-and-rails/13061538#13061538), it's the most practical choice because you don't need to include any dependencies in your Gemfile.