# Capistrano compile assets error - assets:precompile:nondigest?

Tags: deployment, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capistrano

My App seems to be deploying correctly but I'm getting this error:

```
      * executing "cd /home/deploy/tomahawk/releases/20120208222225 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
    servers: ["ip_address"]
    [ip_address] executing command
*** [err :: ip_address] /opt/ruby/bin/ruby /opt/ruby/bin/rake assets:precompile:nondigest RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
```

I've tried solutions here for trying to compile assets: http://lassebunk.dk/2011/09/03/getting-your-assets-to-work-when-upgrading-to-rails-3-1/

And Here: http://railsmonkey.net/2011/08/deploying-rails-3-1-applications-with-capistrano/

And here: http://dev.af83.com/2011/09/30/capistrano-rails-3-1-assets-can-be-tricky.html

Here is my deploy.rb :

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
load 'deploy/assets'

set :default_environment, {
 'PATH' => "/opt/ruby/bin/:$PATH"
}

set :application, "tomahawk"
set :repository,  "repo_goes_here"
set :deploy_to, "/home/deploy/#{application}"
set :rails_env, 'production'
set :branch, "master"

set :scm, :git
set :user, "deploy"
set :runner, "deploy"
set :use_sudo, true

role :web, "my_ip"                         
role :app, "my_ip"                        
role :db,  "my_ip", :primary => true 

set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false
after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup"

namespace :deploy do
    desc "Restarting mod_rails with restart.txt"
    task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
        run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
    end

    [:start, :stop].each do |t|
        desc "#{t} task is a no-op with mod_rails"
        task t, :roles => :domain do ; end
    end
end

task :after_update_code do  
run "ln -nfs #{deploy_to}/shared/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
end
```

Comment: I have exactly the same when deploying my rails 3.1 app. I think that is hidden in the [sprockets rake task](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/sprockets/assets.rake) somewhere, but I don't see it. Could it be that the `precompile:assets:nondigest` task logs a warning to stderr or something, and this is picked up by capistrano?

Comment: To tell you the truth this nondigest stuff is a little out of my scope of understanding (still wrapping my head around precompile :) - but I showed this to a friend and he said this ... "I dont think those are errors at all
I think the output is messed up somehow, thinks its an error stream when its using the normal output as long as the deploy finishes you should be fine, a real error stops execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I later noticed that capistrano wasn't able to delete old releases, I got an error:

```
*** [err :: ip_address] sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

I found this link regarding this error:
http://www.mail-archive.com/capistrano@googlegroups.com/msg07323.html

I had to add this line to my deploy file:

```
default_run_options[:pty] = true
```

This also solved the weird error I was getting above.

The official explanation, which I don't understand :)

No default PTY. Prior to 2.1, Capistrano would request a pseudo-tty for each command that it executed. This had the side-effect of causing the profile scripts for the user to not be loaded. Well, no more! As of 2.1, Capistrano no longer requests a pty on each command, which means your .profile (or .bashrc, or whatever) will be properly loaded on each command! Note, however, that some have reported on some systems, when a pty is not allocated, some commands will go into non-interactive mode automatically. If you’re not seeing commands prompt like they used to, like svn or passwd, you can return to the previous behavior by adding the following line to your capfile:  default_run_options[:pty] = true

Answer (score 7):

first don't forget to add the gem below

```
group :production do
 gem 'therubyracer'
 gem 'execjs'
end
```

then in your cap file just add this line in your after_update_code

```
run "cd #{release_path}; rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production "
```

this worked fine for me ;)

cheers,

Gregory HORION

Comment: hey dude, i would advice you not to show your ip in your message, this can lead to some attacks on your server ;) cheers

Comment: Woops! :)  gotta watch that copy and paste!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. I have added this to my deploy.rb (for adding option '--trace'):

```
namespace :deploy do
  namespace :assets do
    task :precompile, :roles => :web, :except => { :no_release => true } do
      run "cd #{current_path} && #{rake} RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile --trace"
    end
  end
end
```

And error seems to be just notice :

```
*** [err :: my-server] ** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me:

1) Add rvm-capistrano to your Gemfile

2) in confg/deploy, add the lines:

```
require 'rvm/capistrano'
set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.2' # Set to your version number
```

3) You may also need to set :rvm_type and :rvm_bin_path.  See [this Ninjahideout blog](http://blog.ninjahideout.com/posts/rvm-system-wide-installs-and-capistrano-integration) that goes into more detail.

4) apt-get/yum install nodejs on your server

(See my reply to this [related Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038350/bundle-install-issue-with-libv8-and-rails/13061538#13061538).)

Answer (score 0):

The message you see is the output of `rake assets:precompile` .

When you run `rake assets:precompile`, how to avoid default output

the solution is to **add `-q` behand your command**,

analysis is below, if you want to see:

```
# :gem_path/actionpack/lib/sprockets/assets.rake
namespace :assets do

  # task entry, it will call invoke_or_reboot_rake_task
  task :precompile do
    invoke_or_reboot_rake_task "assets:precompile:all"
  end

  # it will call ruby_rake_task
  def invoke_or_reboot_rake_task(task)
    ruby_rake_task task
  end

  # it will call ruby
  def ruby_rake_task(task, fork = true)
    env    = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'production'
    groups = ENV['RAILS_GROUPS'] || 'assets'
    args   = [$0, task,"RAILS_ENV=#{env}","RAILS_GROUPS=#{groups}"]
    ruby(*args)
  end
end

# :gem_path/rake/file_utils.rb
module FileUtils

  # it will call sh
  def ruby(*args,&block)
    options = (Hash === args.last) ? args.pop : {}
    sh(*([RUBY] + args + [options]), &block)
  end

  # it will call set_verbose_option
  # and if options[:verbose] == true, it do not output cmd
  #   but default of options[:verbose] is an object
  def sh(*cmd, &block)
    # ...
    set_verbose_option(options)
    # ...
    Rake.rake_output_message cmd.join(" ") if options[:verbose]
    # ...
  end

  # default of options[:verbose] is Rake::FileUtilsExt::DEFAULT, which is an object
  def set_verbose_option(options) # :nodoc:
    unless options.key? :verbose
      options[:verbose] =
        Rake::FileUtilsExt.verbose_flag == Rake::FileUtilsExt::DEFAULT ||
        Rake::FileUtilsExt.verbose_flag
    end
  end
end

# :gem_path/rake/file_utils_ext.rb
module Rake
  module FileUtilsExt
    DEFAULT = Object.new
  end
end

# :gem_path/rake/application.rb
          # the only to solve the disgusting output when run `rake assets:precompile`
          #   is add a `-q` option.
          ['--quiet', '-q',
            "Do not log messages to standard output.",
            lambda { |value| Rake.verbose(false) }
          ],
          ['--verbose', '-v',
            "Log message to standard output.",
            lambda { |value| Rake.verbose(true) }
          ],
```