# rails / capistrano - error compiling assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

When I deploy with capistrano I get an error (and rollback) when capistrano attempts to run assets:precompile.

I'm using rails 3.2.1, bundler 1.0.22, capistrano 2.11.2

If I run rake assets:precompile from /webapps/myapp/current it runs successfully.

error:

```
failed: "sh -c 'cd /webapps/myapp/releases/20120304160347 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile'"
```

deploy.rb

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
load 'deploy/assets'
set :application, "myapp"
set :domain, '24.17.71.95'
set :repository,  "." 
set :deploy_via, :copy
set :local_repository, '/home/me/myapp/.git'
set :deploy_to, '/webapps/myapp/'
set :scm, :none #:git
set :user, 'me'
set :password, 'me$pw'
# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `git`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, `subversion` or `none`
default_run_options[:pty] = true 
role :web, domain                       # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, domain                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db, domain, :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run
set :branch, 'master'
# if you're still using the script/reaper helper you will need
# these http://github.com/rails/irs_process_scripts
before "deploy:assets:precompile", "bundle:install"
# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:
 namespace :deploy do
   task :start do ; end
   task :stop do ; end
   task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
     run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
   end
 end
```

Comment: Please include more of the output from the cap deploy.

Comment: Will do, just a minute or two.

Comment: What happens if you ssh into your server and execute exactly cd /webapps/myapp/current && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the asset precompiling task should be one of the last (or even the last one) tasks that are beeing executed.

So please try to move

```
load 'deploy/assets'
```

out of deploy.rb into Capfile (root folder of your Rails app) and paste it as the last line of the file.

Comment: I don't think, that's a good idea. It is a task you are calling for deployment (that's why it belongs into deploy.rb) and not a Capistrano related configuration (that's when you put it into the Capfile).

Comment: this worked to solve a similar problem I was having where rake could not be found in any of my sources. why does this work?

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202675/capistrano-compile-assets-error-assetsprecompilenondigest/13061596#13061596).

If that fails, try the advice in http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2012/02/heroku-and-rails-3-2-assetprecompile-error/