# Rails 3. Could not find libv8-3.3.10.4 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I'm trying to run `cap deploy` for the first time but I get this error...

```
[11.12.13.140] sh -c 'cd /var/www/releases/20120302151641 && bundle install --gemfile /var/www/releases/20120302151641/Gemfile --path /var/www/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'
** [out :: 11.12.13.140] Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory.
** [out :: 11.12.13.140] Could not find libv8-3.3.10.4 in any of the sources
```

I have this on my Gemfile `gem 'libv8', '3.3.10.4'`

I packaged my gems in the vendor/cache directory and I do have this gem `libv8-3.3.10.4-x86_64-linux`

Why do I keep on getting this error? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 8):

Do `gem install --version '=3.3.10.4' libv8` on the target machine.

Comment: This answer fails for me, with:ERROR:  Error installing libv8:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
        /usr/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you need packaging? Capistrano does `bundle install` for me, so I just did

```
rm -rf vendor/cache
bundle install
```

and problem gone because now gems compiled on the target machine.

If you still need packaging see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038350/bundle-install-issue-with-libv8-and-rails) question for fine-grainded solution.

Comment: +100 I've been struggling with this for a long time. Just removed that folder and everything's happy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your local environment is different to your production environment, the easiest is to download the version you need for your production environment from:

https://rubygems.org/gems/libv8/versions

Save it into your vendor/cache directory.