# Could not find libv8 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, therubyracer

Bundle install works well. In my gemfile.lock I have

```
therubyracer (0.10.2)
  libv8 (~> 3.3.10)
```

But trying to start the server returns:

```
/Users/toptierlabs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:90:in `materialize': 
Could not find libv8-3.3.10.4 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

The gem is correctly installed:

```
gem list libv8 

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

libv8 (3.3.10.4 ruby x86_64-darwin-10)
```

Please help! I don´t know what to do, I have been stucked with this problem.
I am using ruby 1.9.3.

```
gem which 
/Users/toptierlabs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/libv8-3.3.10.4-x86_64-darwin-10/lib/libv8.rb
```

Comment: what does return `gem which libv8`?

Comment: /Users/toptierlabs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/libv8-3.3.10.4-x86_64-darwin-10/lib/libv8.rb

Comment: ok I do not know much about mac environment, but that `-x86_64-darwin-1‌​0` sounds weird to me... I would follow that lead

Comment: maybe related to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038350/bundle-install-issue-with-libv8-and-rails

Comment: or this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905820/gem-install-therubyracer-fails-on-mac-os-x-lion

Answer (score 4):

I did rvm reinstall 1.9.3 and bundle update.
It installed libv8-3.3.10.4-x86_64-darwin-12 instead of libv8-3.3.10.4-x86_64-darwin-10 and it worked.