# bundle install fails but gem install succeeds

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, bundle-install

I have often seen that `bundle install` will try to build a gem but `gem install` fetches the same gem from remote repository. I thought `bundler` would also try to fetch the gems. Can anyone explain the difference? For example, if my `Gemfile` lists `libv8`, `bundle install` fails with the following error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. 
....
An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

But, `gem install` succeeds by just fetching it. `man bundle-install` has this to say:

> If this is the first time you run bundle install (and a Gemfile.lock
>   does not exist), bundler will fetch all remote sources, resolve
>   dependencies and install all needed gems.

Why does `bundle install` decide to build the gem while `gem install` just installs it? Also, it may build for some version but just install it for some other version of the same gem? For example, `thrift-0.9.0.1.patched` is built but `thrift-0.9.2.0` is installed on my machine. Why the difference?

Comment: Are you sure the same gem version for libv8 is what's installed locally? Bundler resolves gem dependencies, so Bundler may be trying to install a version of the libv8 gem that's different from what the gem install command tries. Where's the rest of the error output for why Bundler couldn't install the gem?

Comment: Bundler tries to install v3.16.14.3 which is what gem install installs. The error is due to compiler mismatch when trying to build native code (C++).

Comment: Not sure if this helps or not, but install nodejs; in your Gemfile if you have therubyracer, comment that out. See if that works (based off of an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24720497/191741)